# Find Index of array

Tags: typescript

I have an JSON object that looks like this . I need to find the index based on ID so that I can retrieve the value. indexOf function seem to work for array of single values. This is almost find index of an array within an array.

I have an for loop that gets me the ID from a different object, my goal is to pull the associated value from the below object without iterating through each element. (Below is a sample actual object has about 50 Id and Value's)

```
"Field": [
    {
      "id": 360000165507,
      "value": 123
    },
    {
      "id": 360000128528,
      "value": null
    },
    {
      "id": 360000122207,
      "value": xyz
    },
    {
      "id": 360000091348,
      "value": abc
    },
 ]
```

Thanks
Ashish

Comment: Just use the `for` loop to access the data - any Array extension method you use is going to loop the entire array anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `filter()` to get the object, then return the `indexOf()` the object in the `obj.Field` array:

```js
let obj={Field:[{id:360000165507,value:123},{id:360000128528,value:null},{id:360000122207,value:"xyz"},{id:360000091348,value:"abc"}]};

function getIndexById(id){
    let resObj = obj.Field.filter((el) => el.id == id)[0]
    return obj.Field.indexOf(resObj)
}

console.log(getIndexById(360000122207))
```